# What can i do if AWS Cognito doesn't trigger a migration Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have 2 AWS Cognito UserPools. One of them is in my "old" Account and one is in the "new" Account. Now I want to migrate users using a lambda trigger but the lambda wouldn't be executed, even when I make a simple HTTP request and check if this was sent. I also can't find any logs on this issue.

The only error I got is that my frontend is showing an error called "UserNotFoundException".

Comment: You need much more detail than this.
Which guide did you follow particularly / which cognito hook did you put the lambda?...